# Get all direct children of element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Helo,

Why isn't this working?

```
$('#someID>*');
```

I want to only get the direct children of #someID.

```
<div id="someID">
   <p><a/></p>
   <div><p/></div>
</div>
```

Should only return the first `<p>` and the inner `<div>`.

Thank you.

Comment: What does it actually return?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Chriszuma. I didn't bother to check what it was returning. Turns out there was another element in between. So that does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4waEX/).

What results are you getting?

Comment: No problem. Glad you've got it. Tip: for future readability (and debuggin), add spaces between selectors. i.e.
$('#someID > *');

Comment: I'm a fan of crowded code, kill off any unnecessary white space. Like `a=b` is enough, you don't need `a = b` etc, but that's just me. :)

Answer (score 3):

it does but your example isn't valid html:

```
<div id="someID">
    <p><a></a></p>
    <div><p></p></div>
</div>
```

check the log in the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ef6/1/

first one outputs **p, div** second one **p, a**

Comment: It's just an example to show what I wanted to get, it's not real code. Also, I think you can short-close <a/> and <p/> if you want, but not sure why you would ever do that. Just an example though, thanks.

Comment: That's the point. It doesn't work with your example. It does with closing tags though.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it would be [`$('#someID').children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't self close an anchor link.

This example works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/uBebv/

```
<div id="someID">
    <p><a></a></p>
   <div><p/></div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(function() {
    console.log( $('#someID>*') )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly close your html tags.

In particular, the closing tag for the [`<a>` element is required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2), while it's [optional for the `<p>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). See the official [html4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html) specs.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbjxS/).